# How to use ngrok tunnels correctly for best workflow with wordpress and docker compose yml

Tags: wordpress, docker-compose, ngrok

I am using `docker-compose.yml` to run Wordpress container with a few other containers...

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  # here is our mysql database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  # here is our wordpress server
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      # our persistent local data re routing
      - .:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/testing:delegated
      - ./plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
      - ./uploads:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      # our local dev environment
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
      DEVELOPMENT: 1
      # docker wp config settings
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
        /* Development parameters */
        define('WP_CACHE', false);
        define('ENVIRONMENT', 'local');
        define('WP_DEBUG', true);

  # here is our mail hog server
  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
    ports:
      - "8025:8025"
```

This `docker-compose.yml` builds my Wordpress site accessible `http://localhost`

For me to setup a ngrok tunnel, I have to do add a new one via the ngrok dashboard and follow these instructions...

[image]

Which adds my auth code to the `.ngrok/ngrok.yml` in my user root and then fires up a tunnel for https and http. This method seems a bit long winded as I have to do this every time I start a new session.

Is it possible to run this code on `docker-compose up -d` as part of my local environment?

---

Also every time I start a new session my tunnel URL changes. I've created a custom domain in my ngrok dashboard, this is what it looks like with no tunnel running...

[image]

Then if I start my tunnel (using the default method shown above)...

```
Last login: Sat Oct 17 17:17:53 on ttys005
joshmoto@Joshs-iMac ~ % unzip /Users/joshmoto/Desktop/ngrok.zip
Archive:  /Users/joshmoto/Desktop/ngrok.zip
replace ngrok? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: y
  inflating: ngrok                   
joshmoto@Joshs-iMac ~ % 

ngrok by @inconshreveable                                                (Ctrl+C to quit)
                                                                                         
Session Status                online                                                     
Account                       joshmoto (Plan: Basic)                                     
Version                       2.3.35                                                     
Region                        United States (us)                                         
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040                                      
Forwarding                    http://############.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:80        
Forwarding                    https://############.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:80       
                                                                                         
Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90                
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

And then look back at my custom domain, it's exactly the same, `0 tunnels`.

[image]

---

Also another issue with Wordpress / Docker Compose, after I have the above tunnel running.

`http://############.ngrok.io` ajax does not seem to work, but network assets load fine apart from fonts. [See full error console log here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBTi8.png).

I'm not too fussed as my main objective is to have a working `https` url for webhooks.

`https://############.ngrok.io` url does work, but no assets load at all. However for webhook usage it does the trick.

But these tunnel URL's change every time I restart the terminal ngrok session so getting a custom url to work would be better.

---

I've tried using docker image [wernight/ngrok](https://hub.docker.com/r/wernight/ngrok/) with these `docker-compose.yml` configs...

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  # ngrok
  ngrok:
    image: wernight/ngrok:latest
    environment:
      NGROK_AUTH: #################################################
      NGROK_LOOK_DOMAIN: localhost
      NGROK_PROTOCOL: http
      NGROK_PORT: 80
      NGROK_BINDTLS: true
      NGROK_HOSTNAME: mycustomdomain.eu.ngrok.io
      NGROK_REMOTE_ADDR: 127.0.0.1:80

    ports:
      - "4040:4040"

    ...
```

And then command lines `docker-compose down` and `up -d`, but the custom ngrok url page returns...

> Tunnel mycustomdomain.eu.ngrok.io not found

---

What is the best way to configure ngrok with docker compose wordpress image for optimum workflow, with custom ngrok domain.

I've tried these ngrok wordpress options ([see ngrok wp docs](https://ngrok.com/docs#wordpress)) too to fix assets...

```
WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |

  /* ngrok wp urls overrides */
  define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
  define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

But this returns this warning below when I `docker-compose up -d` and breaks `localhost` version and does not change anything on ngrok tunnel urls.

```
WARNING: The _SERVER variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

Any ideas would be great thanks.

Comment: What about the tunnel config for ngrok? To avoid the error: `Your configuration file must define at least one tunnel when using --all`

Answer (score 0):

The value NGROK_LOOK_DOMAIN should be using the localhost of Docker, not the generic localhost,

Use this one instead

> NGROK_LOOK_DOMAIN = host.docker.internal

this is working on my end

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work in three steps:

1. Use this docker-compose.yaml:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

volumes:
    mysite_wordpress_content:
    mysite_mysql_data:
    
services:
  mysite_mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"    
    volumes:
      - mysite_mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  mysite_wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - mysite_mysql
    image: wordpress:6.3.2
    ports:
      - "8181:80"
    volumes:
      - mysite_wordpress_content:/var/www/html/wp-content

    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysite_mysql:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
```

2. Add the **[Relative URL](https://sparanoid.com/work/relative-url/)** WodPress plugin
3. Launch ngrok with the following command:

```bash
docker run -it --net=host -e NGROK_AUTHTOKEN=<myToken> ngrok/ngrok http --host-header=127.0.0.1:8181 8181
```

(see also [my question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/419322/236357) and [my answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/419323/236357) on the WordPress stackexchange site)